# injected service not executing correctly despite being provided at module level angular 4

Tags: angular, service, observable, subject, angular-providers

I have a service called `VenueAdminInceptionService`

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {VenueAdminInceptionModel} from '../../models/venueadmininceptionmodel/venueadmin.inception.model';

export class VenueAdminInceptionService{

  //pk and url service
  private pkurlsend = new Subject<VenueAdminInceptionModel>();

  sendurlpk(payload: VenueAdminInceptionModel){
    this.pkurlsend.next(payload);
  }

  receiveurlpk(): Observable<VenueAdminInceptionModel>{
    return this.pkurlsend.asObservable();
  }
}
```

it is injected in the app module

```
import {VenueAdminInceptionService} from './services/venueadmin/venueadmin.inception.service';
providers: [VenueService, ModalToggleService, VenueAdminInceptionService],
```

The Service is used in the following way in my routing.

with the `VenueadminactualComponent being the observeable with`
venueprofileComponent`,`venueadmincateringComponent`,`VenuecreatededitComponent`,`VenueroomadminpageComponent`,`VenueadminsocialmediaComponent`

being the obeservers.

the code in the observable in the `VenueadminactualComponent`:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private inceptionservice: VenueAdminInceptionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inceptedroute = this.route.snapshot.url[0].path;
    if(this.inceptedroute === 'venue-admin'){
      this.permission = 'venue';
    }
    if(this.inceptedroute === 'suits-venue-admin'){
      this.permission = 'suits';
    }

    const payload = {
      pk: this.route.snapshot.params.pk,
      permission: this.permission,
    };
    this.inceptionservice.sendurlpk(payload);

  }
```

and then each observable is subscribed as such.

```
constructor(private inceptionservice: VenueAdminInceptionService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inceptionservicevar = this.inceptionservice.receiveurlpk()
      .subscribe(
        (incep: VenueAdminInceptionModel) => {
          this.permission = incep.permission;
          this.venueid = incep.pk;
        }
      );
    console.log(this.permission);
    console.log(this.venueid);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.inceptionservicevar.unsubscribe();

  }
```

the console logs are blank. Which makes me think nothing is getting through.

I thought it could be my apps architecture, but thats why I provided the service app module wide.

the routing, in case that matters at all, although I can't see how, is as follows:

```
{path: 'venue-admin/:pk', component: VenueadminactualComponent,
    children:[
      {path: 'profile', component: VenueprofileComponent },
      {path: 'catering', component: VenueadmincateringComponent},
      {path: 'venuepage', component: VenuecreateeditComponent},
      {path: 'room', component: VenueroomadminpageComponent},
      {path: 'socialmedia', component: VenueadminsocialmediaComponent},
    ]},
```

Assistance please! Punch and Pie await!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs need to be in the response to the subscribe:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.inceptionservicevar = this.inceptionservice.receiveurlpk()
      .subscribe(
        (incep: VenueAdminInceptionModel) => {
          this.permission = incep.permission;
          this.venueid = incep.pk;
          console.log(this.permission);
          console.log(this.venueid);
        }
      );        
  }
```

Otherwise they are running before the subscribe has returned data (because the subscribe is happening asynchronously).